# Is there a chance that array_slice is bugged - returning wrong

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a chance to array_slice is bugged (using PHP 8.0.12)
I were looking for best way to get few elements(limited) of array with possible offset so tried to array_slice but its keep return me wrong index then i expect

I have array with objects from database and they looks like(ill write only id)
$questions simplified to only id

```
$limit = 1;
$questions = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'stage' => 1,
        'question_order' => 0,
        'many_answers' => 0,
        'points' => 5.5,
        'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
        'question' => "Czy Johnny Deep grał Jack'a Sparow'a?",
        'time' => "00:00:10"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 3,
    'stage' => 1,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 0,
    'points' => 4.5,
    'spread_points_in_time' =>0,
    'question' => "Producent laptopa Darka",
    'time' => "00:00:00"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 1,
    'stage' => 1,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 0,
    'points' => 10,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
    'question' => "Która klawiatura jest mechniczna",
    'time' => "00:00:10"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 8,
    'stage' => 2,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 0,
    'points' => 30,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 1,
    'question' => "2*2",
    'time' => "00:00:30"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 4,
    'stage' => 2,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 0,
    'points' => 30,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
    'question' => "Który język programowania ma dostęp do komórek pamięci komputera?",
    'time' => "00:00:30"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 7,
    'stage' => 2,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 0,
    'points' => 30,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
    'question' => "2+2",
    'time' => "00:00:30"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 10,
    'stage' => 3,
    'question_order' => 1,
    'many_answers' => 1,
    'points' => 5,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
    'question' => "Jaki jest symbol chemiczny srebra?",
    'time' => "00:00:00"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 11,
    'stage' => 3,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 1,
    'points' => 5,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
    'question' => "Jaka jest żywotność ważki?",
    'time' => "00:00:00"
    ),

    array(
    'id' => 9,
    'stage' => 3,
    'question_order' => 0,
    'many_answers' => 0,
    'points' => 5,
    'spread_points_in_time' => 0,
    'question' => "W którym roku Titanic zatonął na Oceanie Atlantyckim 15 kwietnia podczas dziewiczej podróży z Southampton?",
    'time' => "00:00:00"
    )
);

echo json_encode(
    array(
    'all' => $questions,
    'limit' => $limit,
    'sliced' => array_slice($questions, 0, $limit),
    )
);
```

so when i try array_splice(array, 0, 1) i would expect 1 so id should be 2 but instead i get object which have id 1

i also tried with flag to keep indexed but then i end up same but with true index of object with id 1 (then key is 2)
If i put limit as 2 then i get object with id 1 and also object with id 2 (flag to keep indexed also return me properly to objects 2 and 0)

Also tried to remove id from every object by

```
foreach($questions as $key => $question)
{
unset($questions[$key]['id'];
}
```

But this didnt changed anything

[image: Output]

$questions source https://pastebin.com/wDfJdm9Z

Comment: array_splice or array_slice? (mind the "p"). /E: and your question misses example input, it is not clear what magic objects you have in your database, so .... .

Comment: Exactly slice to get extracted element

Comment: okay, and do you use the index (key) as the ID and it is numeric (integer)?

Comment: Yeah it's numeric

Comment: array_slice does not preserve the index unless you `$preverse_keys`, see here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php - maybe that's your issue?

Comment: Yeah i know, i wrote a bit about i tried with that
Flag work good i mean good as it can relative to objects it returns but i got wrong objects

"i also tried with flag to keep indexed but then i end up same but with true index of object with id 1 (then key is 2) If i put limit as 2 then i get object with id 1 and also object with id 2 (flag to keep indexed also return me properly to objects 2 and 0)"

Comment: then likely your question is not entirely clear to me, it is perhaps easier to grasp if you provide actual example values (even in a simplified form where the value in the array is just the ID instead of the object with that ID); `$questions = [...]`.

Comment: There was hand writed array and also screen i putted it in array and code zone so maybe now will look more clear
Also at the end of post added paste bin with full source

Comment: Can you just put the PHP in one block with enough code to actually reproduce the issue just like that? Also, simplify. It looks irrelevant that the objects have properties like `points`, `many_answers`, ...etc. Keep it to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: trincot thanks for hint, done

Comment: @DamianChudobiński ran the exact code you have above in https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler, and got the id2 element in the slice. are you sure your page isn't cached with some old version of the code or something?

Comment: also did and across all current php versions and there is no change. slice is always the first element with ID=2, see here: https://3v4l.org/F9piH

Comment: Yup did simple changes to check it and they change
I got an idea that may xampp could affect it

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of combinations i figured it out
I were sorting this array before everything with forcing keys
So in sorting it looked like

```
    foreach($toSort as $key => $item)
    {
        foreach($ids as $idKey => $id)
        {
            if($item['id'] == $id)
            {
                $sorted[$idKey] = $item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So for example array could end up with wrong order of keys like:

```
array(
[1] => item2,
[0] => item1,
[2] => item3
);
```

I were expecting array gona shove key 0 to be index 0 but don't looks like
Setting something to exact key isn't same as set something to set at exact index

**SOLUTION WAS add ksort($sorted) before return $sorted**